# How is com.solacesystems.jms.SolConnection.mClientID field set by default?

Tags: solace

How is com.solacesystems.jms.SolConnection.mClientID field set by default?

The string consists of 3 parts. The first part is the hostname. What's the logic for setting the 2nd and 3rd parts?

Where can I find Solace JMS driver code?

Answer (score 0):

The private member mClienID isn't accessible. You can read it's value with method `SolConnection.getClient()`. 
You can overwrite its default value with the method `SolConnectionFactory.setClientID()` or from the Solace Admin GUI.

It is the 'client ID' for this connection and it uniquely identifies this client from others. If your client crashes and restarts, the appliance will know it's the same App continuing it's session or not by looking at this client ID. For many scenarios, Client ID doesn't matter, but just in case, the API and appliance automatically assign a unique ID to this connection: hostname (internal) (internal)

For downloads, try here: https://solace.com/downloads/